How do I put together a Blazor Page that will call a javascript file that needs to import an ESModule?
There is the following application called Fantastic Dice that is a javascript module. It can be loaded as such from the example provided here from this page.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dice-es6-module-cdn-lhbs99?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A1%2C1-2%2C1
I have tried doing this in a Blazor page with no success.
I have the following javascript file called dice.js
import DiceBox from "https://unpkg.com/@3d-dice/dice-box@1.0.8/dist/dice-box.es.min.js";

export function DiceBoxCall() {
    let Box = new DiceBox("#dice-box", {
        assetPath: "assets/",
        origin: "https://unpkg.com/@3d-dice/dice-box@1.0.8/dist/",
        theme: "default",
        themeColor: "#feea03",
        offscreen: true,
        scale: 6
    });

    Box.init().then(async (world) => {
        Box.roll(["4d20", "4d12", "4d10", "4d8", "4d6", "4d4"]);
    });
}

I call it from Blazor using the JSRuntime library
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("DiceBoxCall");

This loads, but It cannot find DiceBoxCall. I'm pretty sure its the import but that import is vital to everything. The library fantastic dice uses is an ESModule and the import call is loading the library into a class object. I cannot find any other example that would help me here.
Edit:
I tried using  in the following way with no success.
<HeadContent>
    <script type="module">
        import DiceBox from "@3d-dice/dice-box"
    </script>
</HeadContent>


"you include the JavaScript in the HeadContent section of the Razor page and then add the module attribute" I have to be missing something then because I followed it as well which means there is something with Blazor and Javascript I am not understanding. Do you have an example of your what the  content looks like in including the javascript? I'm positive I have the JSRuntime correct. Just not how to get the Javascript included correctly.

My project is Blazor Server .NET8

Interactive Server. Also the example code I have above is the code that comes from the CDN example. I have tried the documentation example as they have it written. The problem is obviously that import line they use to load a module. I tried  and that will not compile for me. I am using the example like you, but as you said you made "adjustments". I therefore must not understand how to successful load an ESModule into a blazor app. I would very much like to see how you loaded the module.

 will not compile for me. It says that "3d is not valid at the start of a code block. Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(", and "{" are valid for the line for import. If I use the CDN version it still errors out. It doesn't like the @ symbol I suppose.

The example you provided does work, but it doesn't work in a way I need to work for me. The example I gave above is what I need because I would like to be able to reroll using JSRuntime so I can run other attributes. Thank you for the code, but in the end, what you gave me brings me right back to my original problem.

Just tried the approach similar to what I described in this post and it seems to be working.
I have three files:

DiceRoller.razor page layout

    @page "/DiceRoller"
    <h3>DiceRoller</h3>
    <div id="dice-box"></div>


DiceRoller.razor.cs page code-behind (partial class)

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

namespace BlazorServerJS.Pages;

public partial class DiceRoller : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    private IJSRuntime JS { get; set; } = default!;
    private IJSObjectReference? _jsModule;
 
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        _jsModule ??= await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
            "import", "./Pages/DiceRoller.razor.js");

        await _jsModule.InvokeVoidAsync("DiceBoxCall");

        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }
}


DiceRoller.razor.js (just because I like to store .js and .css next to respective pages).

import DiceBox from "https://unpkg.com/@3d-dice/dice-box@1.0.8/dist/dice-box.es.min.js";

export function DiceBoxCall() {
    let Box = new DiceBox("#dice-box", {
        assetPath: "assets/",
        origin: "https://unpkg.com/@3d-dice/dice-box@1.0.8/dist/",
        theme: "default",
        themeColor: "#feea03",
        offscreen: true,
        scale: 6
    });

    Box.init().then(async (world) => {
        Box.roll(["4d20", "4d12", "4d10", "4d8", "4d6", "4d4"]);
    });
}


I got this working in a Vanilla Project. Thank you! But now I am stuggling in clearing the board when I want to reroll, and it is definitely because I create a new DiceBox object each time. Now I need a way to initialize the DiceBox object once and be able to reuse that. I tried placing the new DiceBox object and Box.init() in an js initialize() function, but when I called Box.roll from a new js function RollDice(), it says Box is null.

Nevermind. I did finally get this work with a button and it does clear it. Thank you!
